# text input is correct but does show as false

Tags: python, string, tkinter

I wrote a program that should create a random number of strings and chars. Then the user should write the text and the 'check' button should check if the input of the user is the same.
However i keep getting the error that the text is not correct even if i copy and paste the text, list or only the words.
I am new to asking questions so be gentle to me :)

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import * 
import random
from random import randint
import string


root = Tk()
root.title('jw-tex')
root.geometry('1200x800')
root.resizable(False,False)
root.configure(bg = 'yellow')

#beauty vars
button_bg = "grey"

#text vars
chars = string.ascii_letters

i = 1
inserted_words = []

def random_string_generator(str_size, allowed_chars):
    return ''.join(random.choice(allowed_chars) for x in range(str_size))
 

def start_program():

    def random_strings():
        range_ = randint(4,15)
        size = randint(4,10)
        random_string_generator

        for i in range(size):
            to_insert = random_string_generator(size, chars)
            inserted_words.append(to_insert)
            text_display.insert(INSERT, to_insert)
            text_display.insert(INSERT, " ")
        print(inserted_words)   

    def check():
        startindex = "1.0"
        endindex = len(inserted_words)
        endindex_correct = str(endindex) + ".0"
        correct_text = inserted_words
        current_text = write_display.get(startindex, endindex_correct)

        if (correct_text == current_text) :
            print("CORRECT :D")
        else:
            print("false")
            print(correct_text)

    text_display = Text()
    text_display.pack() 
    text_display.configure(width = "100", height = "5") #write text and check if correct
    
    write_display = Text()
    write_display.pack()    
    write_display.configure(width = "100", height = "5")

    random_button = Button(text = "show random text ")
    random_button.pack()
    random_button.configure(command = random_strings)

    check_button = Button(text = "check")
    check_button.pack()
    check_button.configure(command = check)     



main_frame = Frame(root)
welcome_label = Label(main_frame, text = "Welcome to the little Things :) ")
welcome_label.pack()
welcome_label.configure(pady = '20',padx = '10000', bg = 'grey', fg = 'white')

start_button = Button(main_frame,text = "Start")
start_button.pack()
start_button.configure(pady = "5",padx = "10" ,bg = button_bg, command = start_program)

main_frame.pack()
main_frame.configure(bg = "grey")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers.

Comment: Print the `repr()` of `correct_text`, rather than the string itself, to see exactly what characters are in it.  I suspect you have a trailing space or newline.

Comment: @jasonharper s
still doesnt resolve the issue.

Comment: That wasn't supposed to resolve the issue, it was supposed to give additional information to help resolve the issue.

Comment: Note that `correct_text` is a list of words whereas `current_text` is a string, so the comparison will always be `False`.  As the comment said, it is quite easy to spot out the issue if you print out the two variables.

Comment: Ah now i understand. Thanks for the help you two . :)